# Inserir assinatura já feita no macro VBA

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, excel-vba, planilha

Só gostaria de inserir uma assinatura feita no próprio Outlook com imagem e texto nesse VBA, mas não sei como. Segue o código:

```
Sub Aplicacao_Fundo()

Dim OutlookApp As Object, OutlookMail As Object
Dim email As String, assunto As String, corpo As String

Set OutlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

Set OutlookMail = OutlookApp.CreateItem(0)

email = ActiveSheet.Range("B4").Value

assunto = "CONFIRMAÇÃO DE ORDEM - " & ActiveSheet.Range("B3").Value & "(" & ActiveSheet.Range("B2").Value & ")"

corpo = Worksheets("Texto").Range("A1").Value

With OutlookMail
    
    .to = email
    .CC = ""
    .BCC = "fulano@fulano.com"
    .Subject = assunto
    .Body = corpo
    .Display ' para envia o email diretamente defina o código  .Send
    

    
    
End With

Set OutlookMail = Nothing

Set OutlookApp = Nothing

    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tente adicionar o seguinte ao codigo do email. Ajuste conforme necessário:

```
  Const MyPath = "C:\Assinatura\"
  Const MyPicture = "Assinatura1.jpg"
  With CreateObject("Outlook.Application").CreateItem(0)
    .Attachments.Add MyPath & MyPicture
     .HTMLBody = "<html><p>This is a picture</p>" & _
                "<img src=cid:" & Replace(MyPicture, " ", "%20") & " height=240 width=180>" & _
                 "<p>Melhores cumprimentos,</p>" & _
                "<p>" & UCase(Environ("USERNAME")) & "</p></html>"
    .Display
  End With
```